# Can I create a Quad-boot laptop with x1 Win 8 & x3 Linux (3 diff distros)

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot

I have a Samsung laptop with Windows 8 on it. (Shipped with Win 8) I want to install Backtrack 5 Linux, Kali Linux, FreeBSD, and Windows 8. Is this possible? No different from installing as a duel boot?

Any pointers or advice on anything I should know before doing this would be great.

As always, Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Should I install Win 8 first then install the other 3 Linux distros after?

EDIT: Also If I wanted to just install 3 Linux distros with no windows is there anything special I should do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both versions are possible.
Install win first because it's deleting any other boot list os'es.
when adding linuxes, take care at bootloader install, otherwise you have to edit manually entries in grub.
get work and succes!

Comment: Thanks, I can't seem to find the "Boot From CD" option. Or boot from anything option. I pressed everything F1-F9 and never saw my BIOS or the option to enter into any set up. Any idea?

Comment: @user2526699 Go to your firmware setup and choose the entries starting with "UEFI: "